# iOS nested resource bundles possible?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-frameworks

i'm about to distribute a little framework i created with [this](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) awesome tutorial and along with it i'll be providing a resource .bundle. In this framework i utilize some open source code that itself has an associated resource bundle. What i would like to do, if possible, is distribute a single .bundle that has within itself the open source library's bundle. is this possible? messing around myself, i've marked the OS library's .bundle in my framework as having a target membership of my framework's bundle... it seems to all link up just fine until i drop that bundle in to any project. the inner bundle is 'red' if i expand it to see its contents.

am i out of luck or is there a trick to pulling this off? thanks!

(i have tried doing all sorts of searching to find anything pertaining to this not being allowed or supported but can't find anything...)

Comment: i should also mention that the third party resource bundle is used by my framework and those implementing my framework will not have to interact with it.

Comment: A "bundle" is just a directory. You can do anything with it that can be done with any other directory.

Comment: precisely why i can't seem to figure out why my inner bundle is marked as red in the project which imports my framework. the outer bundle is fine and i've verified that the inner bundle actually exists within the outer bundle. it just doesn't seem to want to play nice... as mentioned, my framework does properly (to me) mark the 'inner' bundle as belonging to my resources target and is listed in the 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase of such.

Comment: What do you mean "marked red"? Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: what i was describing was the item was listed in the bundle in the file navigation on the left in xCode, but it was listed in red text. i appreciate your help but interestingly enough i havent touched anything other than to restart and it it's suddenly seemingly fixed itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've confirmed that this does indeed work.

the item was marked red perhaps due to some xCode cache funkiness. after coming back to trying this after a few days and a restart the inner bundle is no longer listed in red text and i can successfully load from the inner bundle. no other changes were made.

Comment: Being marked red is usually a "cannot read file" error. Often it's because the project has been moved or there is a file permissions issue.

Comment: yea that's the strange part as nothing has been moved or built or anything along those lines since i ran in to this. i appreciate the help and you confirming the feasibility of this.

Comment: No worries. I'm sure somebody else will run into the same issue and find this in google search results. Remember to mark your answer as accepted (I think new users have to wait before doing so?) otherwise you'll be penalised for having a question with no accepted answer.